# apply group on associated attributes ruby on rails by using kickchart to show the geo chart

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, chartkick

I need to apply group on associated attributes to apply it on pie_chart which is the method of kick chart so I just need to fetch the associated object attribute like

```
= pie_chart array.group(:user)
```

it returns the user object but I need to apply group on user attribute which is username so please if anybody has solution of this answer me.

Comment: Could you provide some more code to make it more obvious what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using kickchart and in kick chart I want to use pie_chart and for that I need to show the chart with the username of every object which is linker and linker is associated with user one linker can be create a user. and I am fetching the linkers array and by this array I need to apply every linker to its user and then the username hopefully you understand now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable#group_by (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Example :

```
array.group_by { |linker| linker.user.username }
```

It will create a `Hash` with the usernames as keys and `Array` of linkers as values